# Как задать переменной значение другой переменной, если она в другом файле

Tags: python

Всем привет
Хочу передать моей переменной то значение, которое есть у другой переменной в другом файле. Как это можно сделать? Пытался гуглить, но как-то не особо вышло. Если у этого есть какое-то название, то можете его тоже написать в ответе, пожалуйста?

Если какая-то библиотека поможет мне это сделать в меньшее количество строк и/или символов, то укажите, пожалуйста, эту библиотеку.
Еще один вопрос: можно еще как-то передать значение переменной, если у меня нужное мне значение другой переменной находится в текстовом документе?

UPD: забыл указать, что нужный мне файл находится в другой папке

Comment: Импортировать другой файл, получить из него ту переменную

Comment: @gil9red забыл указать, что нужный мне файл в другой папке

Comment: Я уже написал развёртнутый ответ, но, оказалось, неправильно понял вопрос, поэтому не на то отвечал :) Используйте `from .folder.file import VAR`. Если в текстовом документе, то выполните `text = open(file.txt).read();exec(text)`.

Comment: @MichaelTetelev, вариант с `exec` фиговая идея, мало ли что там будет :) Тогда уж, в файле хранить что-то в json

Comment: @gil9red да, ты прав, там должно быть много переменных. Но json мне пока еще не очень нужен, поэтому не буду морочиться и моя программа будет создавать документ.py

Comment: @m14440411 Но всё же лучше сразу привыкайте к `json` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как написал пользователь в комментариях, нужно импортировать файл таким путем:

```
from .folder.file import VAR
```

С текстовым файлом повторить нельзя, как я и предполагал